# MASS::lm.ridge coefficients

Tags: r

I'm trying to perform ridge regression using the `lm.ridge` method. My question is how can I get the coefficients of the fitted model? I'm getting different results from calling:

- `model$coef`
- `coef(model)`

Which is the correct one? Also, why do I get different results from calling:

- `coef(model)` and looking at the 1st coefficient, vs.
- `coef(model)[1]`?

Comment: `?lm.ridge` says that outputted coef is "matrix of coefficients, one row for each value of lambda. Note that these are not on the original scale and are for use by the `coef` method."

Comment: Yeah I saw it but i dont understand the meaning (i have only one lambda)

Comment: Given that the OP has read the documentation, but doesn't understand the [statistical] meaning, I think this should be considered on topic.

Comment: It has nothing to do with my statistical understanding, I'm asking which variable should be used...

Comment: If you're asking about R syntax, then this is off-topic.

Answer (score 7):

As `?lm.ridge` says (in describing the `$coef` element of the returned object) [emphasis added]

> coef: matrix of coefficients, one row for each value of ‘lambda’.
>             **Note that these are not on the original scale and are for use
>             by the ‘coef’ method.**

This means, specifically, that the `$coef` element is not intended for end-users ("if you have to ask ..."). (If you want to see how `$coef` is translated, inspect `MASS:::coef.ridgelm`.) In general, it's better practice to use an accessor method such as `coef()`, when it exists, than to extract components from the guts of a returned object using `$` (or `@` for S4 objects) - for exactly this reason.  Package authors provide `coef()` methods for a reason ...

I can't replicate your second question.  Using the model from `?lm.ridge`, the answers seem identical except for the precision with which they are printed ...

```
> m1 <- lm.ridge(y ~ ., longley)
> coef(m1)
                            GNP    Unemployed  Armed.Forces    Population 
    2946.85636017    0.26352725    0.03648291    0.01116105   -1.73702984 
             Year      Employed 
      -1.41879853    0.23128785 
> coef(m1)[1]       
2946.856
```