# lm() gives different results from lm.ridge(lambda=0)

Tags: r, regression

I'm looking for ideas before I do anything so presumptuous as to contact the Core Team to tell them that they have a bug!

I have a regression from which I extract the coefficients like this:

```
lm(y ~ x1 * x2, data=ds)$coef
```

That gives: x1=0.40, x2=0.37, x1*x2=0.09

When I do the same regression in SPSS, I get: beta(x1)=0.40, beta(x2)=0.37, beta(x1*x2)=0.14.  So quite a difference for the interaction.

X1 and X2 are correlated about .75 (yes, yes, I know - this model wasn't my idea, but it got published), so there is quite possibly something going on with collinearity.

Now of course we all want to point and laugh and SPSS, but I thought I'd try lm.ridge() to see if I can get an idea of where the problems are occurring.  So to get started, let's run lm.ridge() with lambda=0 (i.e., not ridge penalty) and check we get the same as with lm():

```
lm(y ~ x1 * x2, lambda=0, data=ds)$coef
```

x1=0.40, x2=0.37, x1*x2=0.14

Oh dear.  lm.ridge() agrees with SPSS and lm() doesn't.

What's really strange here is that I assumed lm.ridge just piggybacks on lm() anyway, so in the specific case where lambda=0 and there is no "ridging" to do, I'd expect the same results.

Unfortunately there are 34,000 cases in the dataset, so a minimal reprex will not be easy to make.

Any ideas what else I can try?  (This is not stopping me from getting work done, but I'm curious now!)

Comment: Have you tried to make a reproducible example? Like, if you run it on just 100 rows? Or on a simulated data set? Or a built-in data set?

Comment: I'm getting the same coefficients from `lm` and `MASS::lm.ridge` using the built-in `mtcars` and `iris` datasets, and also with a much larger data set of my own.

Comment: ...ditto. Don't know what can be done without being able to reproduce.

Comment: can you post the data set somewhere?

Comment: Typo in your second R code snippet, should be `lm.ridge` not `lm` ?

Comment: The issue is that for `lm.ridge`, `model$coef` and `coef(model)` are two different things. The second gives the same result as for `lm()`. This question is addressed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34567594/masslm-ridge-coefficients.

Comment: it's funny that I didn't notice this since I answered the original question!

Comment: hmm. I may have closed this prematurely.  Did you scale/center the coefficients when you ran the regression in SPSS?  What does `coef()` give you ?

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Yes, coef() gives me the same results for lm() and lm.ridge().  So now my problem is (only) that R and SPSS give different answers, which of course is a 50-50 question (i.e., which is "right"?).

Comment: However, lm.ridge()$coef gives a value for the interaction term that agrees with SPSS to the 5th decimal place (0.142577 versus 0.142579), which seems like a strange coincidence, if that's what it is (i.e., if the lm.ridge()$coef values are just random internal numbers that don't really mean very much).

@Ben: Yes, everything was scaled and centered in all cases.

Comment: I think we need (1) a reproducible example (can you subsample, say, 1% of your data set and see if you get similarly differing answers between SPSS and R)? and possibly (2) more precise information about what you asked SPSS to do (it would be nice to implementation details of SPSS's regression routine, but we probably can't have that)

Comment: can you please edit your question to reflect the current state of knowledge?  Then we can vote to reopen it.

Comment: PS you can look at https://github.com/cran/MASS/blob/master/R/lm.ridge.R (or just print `MASS:::coef.ridgelm`) to see what R is doing with the coefficients/the difference between `coef()` and `$coef`.